# Javascript class giving sintax error from it being ok

Tags: javascript

i am uisang this code:

```
Class Addition {
    constructor () {
        
    }

    add (a = 1, b = 1) {
        console.log(a+b)
    }
}
```

but it geeve aan error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Spelling matters in programming and in Stack Exchange posts. It’s `class`, not `Class`. I hope you’re not just here to spread spam via your profile picture.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Syntax is wrong, `class` should be in lowercase:

```
class Addition {
    constructor () {
        
    }

    add (a = 1, b = 1) {
        console.log(a+b)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.